# Unique contacts aren't identified when same user logged in

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1, when I was creating interaction programmatically using `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("testsource", "usertest");` it was creating contact id once and next time it was creating interaction against same contact.

As per requirement I'm just injecting custom values against interaction which is getting created by default by sitecore but it is creating always new contact even when I used IdentifyAs("source","username") at initial inside below code still not getting interaction against same contact for the same user.

```
public class ConvertInteractionFacet : ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase
    {
        private ILogger _logMessage;

        public override void Process(ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipelineArgs args)
        {
            _logMessage = new Logger();
            _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: start ConvertInteractionFacet process12345");
            try
            {
                string planCode = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    var memberActiveAccount = string.Empty;
                    if (Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session != null && Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUserDetails"] != null)
                    {
                        var currentUserDetails = ((UserDetails)Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUserDetails"]);
                        planCode = ((PlanMemberAccount)currentUserDetails.MemberAccounts).PlanCode.ToString();
                        _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: plan member id is " + planMemberId + " and Plan code is " + planCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: plan code not in session");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    _logMessage.Log(LogType.Error, "Error12345.GetActivePlanMemberAccount: " + ex.Message);
                }

                if (args != null && args.XConnectInteraction.Events.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("PlanCode"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("PlanCode", planCode);
                }
                _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: end ConvertInteractionFacet process12345");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logMessage.Log(LogType.Error, "Error12345: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your issue is you are at ConvertToXConnectInteraction pipeline. The tracker is gone at that point. The session is closing. You are dealing with args now, not the tracker that you need to use IdentifyAs(). You are better of calling xConnect directly and forcing your work. But as you know, that will create a new interaction, separate from this one.

Comment: Interaction is always being created new only even programmatically also. for same user next time interaction must be against same contact that last time created.

Comment: we don't want duplicate records in xDB hence trying to inject in args but here how to manage unique contact for same user. means multiple interaction against same existing known contact.